# Jackson xml 2.9.0: @JacksonXmlElementWrapper not working with @JsonCreator & @JsonProperty constructor

Tags: java, xml, jackson, xml-deserialization, jackson-dataformat-xml

I would like that my `ParentClass` has `final` fields, 'brokenChildList' list is wrapped xml element and list items have different tag than the list (`<brokenChildList><brokenChild/></brokenChildList>`).

Here is a snippet of code to reproduce my issues (imports are partially truncated, setters and getters omitted)

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        String xmlString = "<ParentClass><childClass name=\"name1\" value=\"val1\"/><brokenChildList><brokenChild name=\"bc1\" reason=\"bc-val1\"/><brokenChild name=\"bc2\" reason=\"bc-val2\"/></brokenChildList></ParentClass>";
        ParentClass parentClass = xmlMapper.readValue(xmlString, ParentClass.class);
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        xmlMapper.writeValue(stringWriter, parentClass);
        String serialised = stringWriter.toString();
        System.out.println(serialised);
        System.out.println(xmlString.equals(serialised));
    }

    public static class ChildClass {
        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
        private String name;
        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
        private String value;
        //getters & setters
    }
    public static class BrokenChild {
        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
        private String name;
        @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
        private String reason;
        //getters & setters
    }
    public static class ParentClass {
        private final ChildClass childClass;
        private final List<BrokenChild> brokenChildList;
        @JsonCreator
        public ParentClass(
            @JsonProperty("childClass") ChildClass childClass,
            @JsonProperty("brokenChildList") List<BrokenChild> brokenChildList
        ) {
            this.childClass = childClass;
            this.brokenChildList = brokenChildList;
        }

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "childClass")
        public ChildClass getChildClass() {
            return childClass;
        }

        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "brokenChildList")
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "brokenChild")
        public List<BrokenChild> getBrokenChildList() {
            return brokenChildList;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code gives output with `Jackson` version `2.8.10`:

```
<ParentClass><childClass name="name1" value="val1"/><brokenChildList><brokenChild name="bc1" reason="bc-val1"/><brokenChild name="bc2" reason="bc-val2"/></brokenChildList></ParentClass>
true
```

With `Jackson` version `2.9.0` it gives:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Duplicate property 'brokenChildList' for [simple type, class org.test.Main$ParentClass]
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 1]
```

I would like to find a solution (and any version after `2.9.0`) that will give same output with the attached code.

My failed attempts include:

- Replacing `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "brokenChildList")` with `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper` will rename wrapper element as 'brokenChild' which is undesirable.
- Removing `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "brokenChildList")` will rename wrapper element as 'brokenChild' which is undesirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is really tricky because `Jackson` collects metadata from different places: fields, getters, setters, constructor parameters. Also, you can use `MixIn` but in your case it does not appear.

`@JacksonXmlElementWrapper` annotation can be attached to `FIELD` and `METHOD` type elements and this forces you to declare it on getter. Because `ParentClass` is immutable and you want to build it with constructor we need to annotate constructor parameters as well. And this is where collision appears: you have a constructor parameter with `@JsonProperty("brokenChildList")` annotation and getter with `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "brokenChildList")` which reuses the same name. If you would changed `localName` to `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "brokenChildListXYZ")` (added `XYZ`) everything would be deserialised and serialised but output would be different then input.

To solve this problem, we can use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerModifier` class which allows to filter out fields we do not want to use for deserialisation and which creates collision. Example usage:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanDescription;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerModifier;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BeanPropertyDefinition;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class XmlMapperApp {

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.setDeserializerModifier(new BeanDeserializerModifier() {
            @Override
            public List<BeanPropertyDefinition> updateProperties(DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, List<BeanPropertyDefinition> propDefs) {
                if (beanDesc.getBeanClass() == ParentClass.class) {
                    return propDefs.stream().filter(p -> p.getConstructorParameter() != null).collect(Collectors.toList());
                }
                return super.updateProperties(config, beanDesc, propDefs);
            }
        });
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = XmlMapper.xmlBuilder()
                .addModule(module)
                .build();

        //yours code
    }
}
```

To create this example I used version `2.10.0`.

See also:

- [Jackson 2.10 features](https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/jackson-2-10-features-cd880674d8a2)
- [Jackson Release 2.10](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki/Jackson-Release-2.10)

Comment: Thank you. I apologize for my late reply. This works in the sample code and I also implemented this solution to my real application. This would be even better if it could be implemented globally. Now I have to target multiple immutable classes with that 'if' statement. Is it more conventional to have collections represented in xml as `<items><items/><items/></items>` vs `<items><item/><item/></items>`? I suspect that I am being unconventional based on the non-straightforwardness of this solution.

Comment: @VadaVad, `<items><item/><item/></items>` looks much natural, I think. Solution still uses all internal features from library so it is OK. Some problems just to complex to solve them only with annotations.